# I want this function to loop through both lists and return the object that is the same in both

Tags: python, list

These are the lists; note how the second list is made up of objects that need splitting first.

```
gaps = ['__1__', '__2__', '__3__']
questions = ['Bruce Wayne is __1__', 'Clark Kent is __2__', 'Barry Allen is __3__']
```

Here's the code. It seems to work only for the first (zeroth) object, bud that's it - it doesn't even loop.

```
def is_gap(question, gap):
place = 0
while (place < 3):
    question[place] = question[place].split(' ')
    for index in gaps:
            if index in question[place]:
                return index
            else:
                return None
place += 1
print is_gap(questions, gaps)
```

Comment: Because you always return inside the for loop. You probably don't want that else clause at all.

Comment: Also, can you please fix your indentation? I'm not sure whether the last two lines are inside or outside the function or the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python stops executing as soon as it hits a return statement. If you return inside a loop, it'll stop running after one iteration, when it hits the first return statement.